# Electrical panel indicator lights flickering

Tags: indicator

I'm wondering what the underlying mechanism of the flickering of the panel indicator lights is. Are there electronic oscillators of some kind in there?

[image: indicator]

Comment: Have you seen [Why a neon lamp indicator on power strip switch flickers in the dark?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/230259/why-a-neon-lamp-indicator-on-power-strip-switch-flickers-in-the-dark)

Comment: @frizstyler: See [why-a-neon-lamp-indicator-on-power-strip-switch-flickers-in-the-dark](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/230259/why-a-neon-lamp-indicator-on-power-strip-switch-flickers-in-the-dark/365882#365882) for more interesting information.

Comment: Correction: the [Hagar SVN123](http://www.hager.co.uk/product-catalogue/energy-distribution/modular-devices/indicator-lights/indicator-lights/svn123/41839.htm) (you should have linked to the datasheet) has an LED indicator, not a neon.

Comment: Did it always blink?  Or has it recently gone on the blink ;-?

Comment: yes. thanks people. Please dont be hard with me because i didnt find the other question...

Answer (score 0):

If the orange light blinks, then there is at least one, maybe two oscillators.

One to make the light blink and possibly one for a switching power supply to reduce the 230VAC power to a suitable voltage for the LED etc.